# How do I write the transpose function example from Rust by Example?

Tags: rust

I'm following the Rust by Example tutorial and am on the second part of the [Tuples activity](https://rustbyexample.com/primitives/tuples.html) which is to add a `transpose` function using the `reverse` function as a template. This will accept a matrix as an argument and return a matrix in which two elements have been swapped. For example:

```
println!("Matrix:\n{}", matrix);
println!("Transpose:\n{}", transpose(matrix));
```

Expected results:

```
Input Matrix:
( 1.1 1.2 2.1 2.2 )
Transposed output:
( 1.1 2.1 1.2 2.2 )
```

I can't find the right code, here is what I'm trying:

```
// this is defined in the tutorial
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Matrix(f32, f32, f32, f32);

// this is my attempt that does not compile
fn transpose(maat: Matrix) -> (Matrix) {
    let matrix = maat;
    (matrix.0, matrix.2, matrix.1, matrix.3)
}
```

Comment: To expedite our help: what is your code outputting/what is going wrong?

Comment: Please review how to create a [MCVE]. For example, the vast majority of your `main` function has no bearing on your question.

Answer (score 1):

Using `reverse` as the example says and rewriting the `reverse` function to accept `f32`,

```
fn reverse(pair: (f32, f32)) -> (f32, f32) {
    let (a, b) = pair;
    (b, a)
}

fn transpose(mat: Matrix) -> Matrix {
    let (a, b) = reverse((mat.1, mat.2));
    Matrix(mat.0, a, b, mat.3)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to give you the full solution because i would do you a disservice if you're learning Rust.
There's a key ingredient that you're missing at this point of the tutorial. Not your fault.

Matrix is a "tuple struct" (also sometimes called a newtype) and it's covered in a later section of Rust by example.
If you want to peek ahead, in the [section on structs](https://rustbyexample.com/custom_types/structs.html) you'll learn the two pieces you're missing.

**Piece one**: `struct Matrix(f32, f32, f32, f32);` as defined in the tutorial can be destructured in a similar way as the simple tuple.

If you have a `let matrix = Matrix(1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 2.2);` you can do this to create names for its individual elements:

```
let Matrix(r1c1, r2c2, r2c1, r2c2) = matrix
```

What you did (`matrix.0`, `matrix.1`...) works too, though...

**Piece two**. When you want to create a new instance of `Matrix`, you do `Matrix(1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 2.2)`. From your attempt at writing transpose you're trying to return a tuple, but a tuple struct like `Matrix` is a different, incompatible type (that's why it's also called a "newtype")

Answer (score 0):

You need to do three things here:

1. Tell the Display format how to structure the output so that it divides the Matrix into two rows of equal length.

> ```
> impl fmt::Display for Matrix {
>     fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
>         write!(f, "( {} {} )\n( {} {} )", self.0, self.1, self.2, self.3)
>     }
> }
> ```

2. Write the transpose function that will return the matrix in transposed order.

> ```
> fn transpose(mat: Matrix) -> Matrix {
>     return Matrix(mat.0, mat.2, mat.1, mat.3);
> }
> ```

3. call it inside println

> `println!("Transpose:\n{}", transpose(matrix));`